# Writing a Kernel from scratch

Tags: kernel

I'm not sure whether it's the right place for this question. 
I am writing a kernel from scratch and want links or tutorials where I can get a few pointers.

Comment: Are you trying to compile your own version of the Linux or Unix kernels, or write your very own kernel from scratch?

Comment: If you are writing from scratch, you'll need more than a few pointers.

Comment: @DanielQuinn Write my very own kernel from scratch.

Comment: @msw True, For a 32-bit OS, you'd need 4294967296.

Comment: There are many pointers in the linux kernel source :) `grep char*`

Answer (score 15):

[Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) and its associated book, [Tanenbaum's *Operating System Design and Implementation*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131429388). It is, as I understand, *the* OS book, and the book Linus was reading when he started Linux.

Comment: +1, although, what if he wants to write a monolithic kernel? :) http://oreilly.com/catalog/opensources/book/appa.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at MIT's [Xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html), which is a part of some course called "6.828". The [reference material for that course](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/reference.html) also looks good.

You could look at [LoseThos](http://www.losethos.com/), too, although the author appears to be decaying mentally.

Comment: A programmer probably has to be a bit crazy to write an operating system at all.